# C# HttpClient calls get TaskCanceledException when I pause on breakpoints overly long

Tags: c#, timeout, visual-studio-2022, dotnet-httpclient

I'm working on VS2022, and my code makes many HttpRequests for logging purposes.  They are all async calls you can see in the screen shot.
I will pause on a breakpoint and not get back til many minutes later.  When I resume I get this exception.  But why?  The request was made.  It should just be off in the ether doing its thing, and  not care about my breakpoint.

Unless I am missing something about how pause works when debugging.
Can someone please explain why I get these exceptions?

[image]

Comment: Probably just a timeout. Try setting an [infinite timeout](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.http.httpclient.timeout).

Comment: That's not how it works. It can't go off doing it's own thing if the whole application is in break. When in break mode *all* threads are paused. And in any case `await` can be handled on the UI thread, so even if only that was in break you could still have problems.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is it possible to have other threads continue to run when one thread freeze due to breakpoint](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25184400/is-it-possible-to-have-other-threads-continue-to-run-when-one-thread-freeze-due)

Comment: Without know what your `client.SendAsync` is doing (is it the default HTTP client?) then what @ShahinDohan said is 99.99% right. There is a timeout happening that's using actual elapsed time and doesn't care if you're in debug and frozen or not.

Comment: As much as infinite timeout worries me, that does seem to work.  Still, why do these requests timeout? Are they paused when the debugger is paused?

Comment: Think of it this way: the timeout is implemented using a Window kernel timer, which raises a timer event. If the request finishes, the timer is deleted. When you break, all threads pause, at which point any data coming through from the server-side is held in a buffer by the OS. When you continue, the first thing that will happen (before any of that data is dealt with) is that a threadpool thread is woken to handle the timer, marking the request as failed, and waking up your thread/task to catch the error. At this point, the whole request is dumped.

Comment: Ok, sounds like the break is pausing all threads, so time passes and it times out, even though the request to the URL really is not timed out.  I believe this explains it.  Thank you all.

Comment: @DanielWilliams Please feel free to let know if you have any question.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, infinite timeout does need to be used with caution, as it may cause the program to wait indefinitely when encountering network problems, causing the program to become unresponsive.

**Do they pause when the debugger pauses?**

When the debugger is paused, all threads stop executing. This is because the debugger locks the process so you can inspect variables, call stacks, and more.

**Why do these requests time out?**

Because when you pause in the debugger, all code execution stops, including asynchronous operations. This causes any asynchronous network requests made while the debugger is paused to be paused (the data is held in a buffer by the operating system) until you continue executing your code. Then wake up the thread pool thread to handle the timer, mark the request as failed, and wake up the thread/task to catch the error. That’s why there is a timeout.